# difference between .optimize() and and .repartition() for delta file compaction

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

What is the difference between [optimize](https://docs.delta.io/latest/optimizations-oss.html#compaction-bin-packing) for compaction:

```
deltaTable.optimize().executeCompaction()
```

And [repartition](https://docs.delta.io/latest/best-practices.html#compact-files), with the `dataChange` flag off.

```
(spark.read
 .format("delta")
 .load(path)
 .repartition(numFiles)
 .write
 .option("dataChange", "false")
 .format("delta")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .save(path))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OPTIMIZE` is the command that combines (and optionally ZOrdering) of multiple files into bigger files to make reads more optimal, avoid problem with too many small files, etc. ([documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimize.html)). It's performed on the whole table or specific partitions, and can process data that are written by multiple transactions.

One thing that `OPTIMIZE` is doing in contrast to `repartition` - it doesn't reprocess data that are already optimized (although not always if you're doing ZOrdering).  So if you ingested some amount of data, then `OPTIMIZE` can affect only a part of the table, while `repartition` will always process the whole table.  Also, if you use too few partitions when doing `repartition` you have a chance of crashing due memory overload, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex. When files are optimised/repartitioned, what happens to the ingestion times in the delta log .json files? Are they modified in a way such that Ingestion Time Clustering would still work?

Comment: it depends on the DBR version - in newest version it will try to keep that as I remember. But really, OPTIMIZE may not be so needed with introduction of Liquid Clustering: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/clustering.html

Comment: noted, however I'm dealing with time series data which Ingestion Time clustering is best suited for... still not clear to me whether to use LC or ITC tbh... Too many options re how to store data.

Comment: yes, it's explicitly mentioned here: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/11/18/introducing-ingestion-time-clustering-dbr-112.html: "As part of ingestion time clustering, we ensured that other manipulation and maintenance commands, like DELETE, UPDATE, and OPTIMIZE, also preserved the ingestion order to provide customers with consistent and significant performance gains."